# When using int's as boolean values, is it in poor form to use 0's and 1' directly?

Tags: c

Is it better to do this

```
#define INT_TRUE 1
#define INT_FALSE 0

int someFunctionalityIsEnabled = INT_TRUE;
```

or this?

```
int someFunctionalityIsEnabled = 1;
```

It can be safely assumed that false will always be zero and true will be non-zero.

Comment: This is a [frequently asked question](http://www.c-faq.com/bool/booltype.html). Embedding type information isn't good, though.

Comment: In other words, just say `TRUE`, not `INT_TRUE`.

Comment: If at all possible <stdbool.h> should probably be used

Answer (score 7):

> *It can be safely assumed that false will always be zero and true will be non-zero.*

In this case, your question is *almost* pointless: If you are sure that everyone reading your code knows how "true" and "false" are represented as numbers, then you might not *need* those `#define` macros.

---

**Positive side effect of these `#define`s.** I am saying "almost" because these `#define`s still have value: Without names like `TRUE` and `FALSE`, choosing sensible variable names becomes somewhat more important. For example:

```
int is_enabled = 1;
int age_in_years = 1;
```

How can you tell which variable stores a boolean value, and which an integer number? By looking at the variable names. Now, how about this?:

```
int is_enabled = TRUE;
int age_in_years = 1;
```

The `#define`s add some redundancy (besides well-chosen variable names) that helps you recognise the "real" type of those `int` variables more easily.

For this reason of added clarity, I would recommend using such `#define`s, or if you are using a C99-conforming compiler, `#include <stdbool.h>`.

---

**Negative side effect of these `#define`s.** There's also a bad side to declaring a `TRUE` literal. You are saying that "true" may be represented by "any non-zero integer". Defining `TRUE` as being equivalent to `1` is therefore inaccurate, since that is only one out of many possible values meaning "true". (`FALSE` doesn't suffer from this.) This leads to the somewhat absurd consequence that writing `is_enabled == FALSE` will work as expected, but `is_enabled == TRUE` might not. There's two ways out of this issue:

1. DO NOT ever compare boolean values using `==` or `!=`. Instead,

   - DO write `is_enabled` instead of `is_enabled == TRUE`, and
   - DO write `!is_enabled` instead of `is_enabled == FALSE`.
2. CONSIDER re-defining "true" as "the integer number 1" instead of as "any non-zero integer number". (I would not, since it contradicts how C interprets integers as boolean values... but it's a theoretical possibility.)

I recommend you go with #1 for the reason mentioned.

Comment: Plus, it cannot be safely assumed that other developers have only encountered 'false will always be zero and true will be non-zero.'  That's not true in all languages, so it's really nice to have it declared for those of us who can never remember what flavor of bool we're using now.

Comment: If in your boolean logic you use (is_enabled) and (!is_enabled), doesn't that imply that true is nonzero and false is zero?  Then what is the benefit of having these #define's if the rest of your logic already dictates what values true & false must be?

Comment: @AdamS: For instance, `TRUE` and `FALSE` may still be useful when initializing or re-setting variables: `is_enabled = FALSE;` is simpler than having to write, `is_enabled = is_enabled && !is_enabled;`, and `is_enabled = TRUE` is simpler than `is_enabled = is_enabled || !is_enabled;`…

Comment: Right, but why not just do `is_enabled = 1` instead of `is_enabled = TRUE`?

Comment: @AdamS: Read the first part of my answer again: because of the added redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

The result is the same. Using the

```
#define TRUE 1 
#define FALSE 0
```

is more verbose, but it may make your code more readable for future generations (of programmers or your own brain cells) who are maintaining the application and trying to decipher the code.

Comment: Is using an enum an alternative?  (It's been too long since I've coded in C)